# Increment index in file

Tags: linux, text-processing, perl, numeric-data

Alright, it seems I cannot find a way to do what I need.

Let's say I have a text file A like this

```
(freqBiasL2[27])      
(SatBiasL1[27])       
(defSatBiasL2_L1[27]) 
(defSatBiasSlope[27]) 
(defSatBiasSigma[27]) 

(freqBiasL2[28])      
(SatBiasL1[28])       
(defSatBiasL2_L1[28]) 
(defSatBiasSlope[28]) 
(defSatBiasSigma[28]) 

(freqBiasL2[29])      
(SatBiasL1[29])       
(defSatBiasL2_L1[29]) 
(defSatBiasSlope[29]) 
(defSatBiasSigma[29])
```

and so on.
I want to change the index between [] brackets such that each index i is = i+3.

I tried with a combination of for loop and sed, but not working

```
for i in {27..107..1}
do
    i_new=$((i+3))
    sed -e 's/\['$i'\]/\['$i_new'\]/' prova.txt 

done
```

The problem is that it will change the first 27 for 30 but on next interations it will find 2 blocks with index 30 (the changed one and the original).

How can I do it without overwriting the already changed indexes?

Ok thanks, I edit my question for an improvement:
How can I do something similar is if I have 2 indexes like:

```
(freqBiasL2[32][100])
(SatBiasL1[32][101])
(defSatBiasL2_L1[32][102])
(defSatBiasSlope[32][103])
(defSatBiasSigma[32][104])
```

and I want to increment only the second index ignoring the first one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=\[)(\d+)(?=\])/$1+1/ge' prova.txt
```

Explanation:

- `-p` means loop over every line and print the result after every line
- `-e` defines the expression to execute on every line
- `s/from/to/` does a simple substition
- `s/(\d+)/$1+1/ge` matches one or more digits, captures it into `$1`, and then the `e` modifier on the end tells perl that the substition string is an expression: `$1+1` substitutes the value of `$1` plus 1. The `g` modifier means do this substitution globally, i.e. more than once per line.
- `(?<=\[)` is a positive zero-length lookbehind assertion. That means that what comes after it only matches if it's preceded by `[` (which needs to be escaped with `\` as `[` is a special token in regular expressions). The zero-length thing means that it's not part of what will be replaced.
- `(?=\])` is a positive zero-length lookahead assertion. That means that what comes before it only matches if it's followed by `]` (again escaped).

So this will take all numbers between `[` and `]` and increment that number.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `awk`:

```
awk -F '[\\[\\]]' '{if ($2) { sub($2, $2 + 3)}} 1' prova.txt
```

In fact, this can be slightly shortened to:

```
awk -F '[\\[\\]]' '$2 { sub($2, $2 + 3)} 1' prova.txt
```

Comment: Ok, that works!
Now, how can I do something similar is if I have 2 indexes like:

(freqBiasL2[32][100])
(SatBiasL1[32][101])
(defSatBiasL2_L1[32][102])
(defSatBiasSlope[32][103])
(defSatBiasSigma[32][104])

and i want to increment only the second index ignoring the first one?
Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: Yes, of course. If you change nothing else, then the second index will be the fourth field, so you use `$4` instead of `$2`.

Answer (score 3):

I know you've already solved your problem, but FYI you could have solved it with a very simple modification to your code : by inverting the sequence you loop over.

Using `{107..27..-1}` (or more concisely `{107..27}`) would have been enough to solve your problem, since when replacing 30, only the original 30 would have been found, the 27 having not been replaced yet.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -p -e 's/\[(\d+)\]/"[" . ($1+3) . "]"/ge' dad85.txt
```

This perl one-liner replaces any positive integer number (`\d+`) inside square brackets with that number incremented by 3.

It uses the `e` regexp modifer to make `perl` evaluate the replace portion of the `s///` operation as an expression.

Output:

```
(freqBiasL2[30])
(SatBiasL1[30])
(defSatBiasL2_L1[30])
(defSatBiasSlope[30])
(defSatBiasSigma[30])

(freqBiasL2[31])
(SatBiasL1[31])
(defSatBiasL2_L1[31])
(defSatBiasSlope[31])
(defSatBiasSigma[31])

(freqBiasL2[32])
(SatBiasL1[32])
(defSatBiasL2_L1[32])
(defSatBiasSlope[32])
(defSatBiasSigma[32])
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think i've got a solution for the double index as well modifying the command of cas.
This makes the job:

```
perl -p -e 's/\[(\d+)\]\[(\d+)\]/"[" . ($1) . "][" . ($2+40) . "]"/ge' prova.txt
```

Not sure by the way why I need the `. ($1) .` (point with blank space).